# Problema con getConnection

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript, angular6

Estoy intentado conectarme a la base de datos con el modulo promise-mysql desde express con node, mis archivo son los siguientes.
Desde consola me puedo conectar a mysql sin problemas, lo mismo que utilizando phpmyAdmin o Workbench

Al ejecutar recibo el error de

> TypeError: pool.getConnection is not a function

**Keys.ts**

```
export default {

    database : {
        host : 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: '124563',
        database: 'ng_db'
    }
}
```

**database.ts**

```
import mysql from 'promise-mysql';
import keys from './keys';

const pool = mysql.createPool(keys.database);

pool.getConnection()
    .then(connection => {
      pool.releaseConnection(connection);
        console.log('DB is Connected');

    });

export default pool;
```

**gameController.ts**

```
import { Request,Response } from 'express';
import pool from '../database';

class GameController {

    public index (req: Request, res: Response) {
      pool.query('DESCRIBE game');
      res.json('game')

    } 

}
export const gameController = new GameController();
export default gameController;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**El problema es la versión de `promise` que tienes**, creo que estás haciendo el tutorial de Fazt (Angular Mysql CRUD Tutorial, REST API Node & Typescript) para resolverlo solo tienes que ejecutar en la terminal el comando:

```
npm i promise-mysql@3.3.1
```

Tenía exactamente el mismo problema y a mí me funcionó. Saludos.

Comment: ¿es específicamente la versión 3.3.1 o puede ser una mayor como 4.1.1 ?

Comment: Tenía exactamente el mismo problema y a a mí se me soluciono con la solución de LuisBragado gracias. `npm i promise-mysql@3.3.1`

Comment: con la actualización a la versión 3.3.1 funcionó correctamente.